# Повысить эффективность кода

Tags: erlang, производительность

Здравствуйте, только начал изучать Erlang и уже столкнулся с разочарованием по производительности при вычислении математики. К сожалению сам путей повысить производительность не вижу, а руки уже опустились.
Такой код:

```
% делится ли N на какое-нибудь число из списка
% [] - делится, [N] - не делится
del(N, [H|_]) when N rem H=:=0 -> [];
del(N, [_|T]) -> del(N, T);
del(N, []) -> [N].
% список простых чисел от 2 до N
prosto(N) when is_integer(N), N>1 -> prosto(N, [], 2).
prosto(N, Acc, St) when N+1=:=St -> lists:reverse(Acc);
prosto(N, Acc, St) ->prosto(N, del(St, Acc)++Acc, St+1).
```

При создании списка до 200000 выполняется в среднем 39 секунд.
Аналогичный код по функциональности на Java

```
static boolean del(int N, ArrayList<Integer> L){
    int size=L.size();
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if (N % L.get(i)==0) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
static ArrayList<Integer> prosto(int N){
    ArrayList<Integer> res=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=2; i<=N; i++) {
        if (!del(i, res)) res.add(i);
    }
    return res;
}
```

При создании списка той же длины выполняется в среднем 0.75 секунды. В 52 раза быстрее.
**Вопрос**: можно ли создать более эффективный код на erlang ?

Comment: P.S. Повышение эффективности например таким способом:  

    prosto(N) when is_integer(N), N>1 -> prosto(N, [], 3).
    prosto(N, Acc, St) when N+1=:=St -> lists:reverse(Acc);
    prosto(N, Acc, St) ->prosto(N, del(St, Acc)++Acc, St+2).
не считается, хоть оно и уменьшает число итераций вдвое.

Comment: Подозрительно выглядит `del(St, Acc)++Acc`. `[hd(del(St, Acc)]|Acc]` или `[St|Acc]` возможно будут получше.

Comment: @alexz, я пробовал создавать список таким образом, только без математики. Список на 200000 элементов создается очень быстро, то есть не это узкое место программы.  
Похоже именно много математики тормозит, а именно нахождение остатка.

Comment: @RainRaus, я Вас не понимаю (текст комментария не ясен). Я так понимаю, что предложенные мною правки эффекта не дают? Или что?

Соображения такие: делители большей части испытуемых чисел невелики и, соответственно, находятся в конце списка. Большая часть испытуемых чисел отсеиваетя, поэтому поиск делителей занимает много времени. Если новые числа добавлять в хвост, то поиск делителей ускорится (за счёт увеличения времени добавления новых простых). Так это или нет -- надо смотреть профайлером. Ну можно использовать другие структуры данных (напр. array) вместо однонаправленного списка.

Comment: > столкнулся с разочарованием по производительности при вычислении математики

У вас проблема с алгоритмической частью, математика тут не при чём

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже был не прав. Попробуйте добавлять в конец списка.

```
  prosto(N, Acc, St) when N+1=:=St -> Acc;
  prosto(N, Acc, St) ->prosto(N, case del(St, Acc) of [] -> Acc; [N1] -> Acc++[N1] end, St+case St of 2 -> 1; _ -> 2 end ).
```

Поскльку основная часть отсева идёт в начале списка:2, 3...

Ну а не получится -- тоже плюс, научитесь работать с профайлером. Он в erlang'е вроде есть.

Comment: И правда: коды на erlang и java не аналогичны. Так как erlang перебирает делители с больших, а java с меньших. Такая правка:  

    Acc++del(St, Acc)
уменьшает время исполнения до 8 секунд, а это уже не так плохо.  
Посчитал количество итераций при вычислении (примерно 120млн), так вот, erlang столько `rem` выполняет за 4 секунды, то есть половину всего времени.  Результатом доволен в-общем.  
Буду учить erlang дальше.  
Спасибо :)

Comment: @RainRaus Пожалуйста. Но в случае `Acc++del(St, Acc)` я не знаю, делает ли erlang оптимизацию для случая `del(St, Acc) =:= []`. Если нет, то лишний просмотр Acc для каждого отбракованного числа.